# VS 2005 - Command Line Program Crashes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, visual-c++-2005

There is a command line program developed in VS 2005. It processes some file and creates an output file. There is an input file which causes crash, but only in some cases. If program started using command line (either release or debug build is issued) it crashes during processing that file. But, if it is started from VS 2005, by pressing F5 (Debug mode), it works fine, doesn't crash and result is correct. Any hint?
Thanks.

Comment: If it works when running in the debugger, one good way of narrowing it down may be to put debug print statements in the code, like `cout << "Now calling function X\n";`. Start at a high level in `main`, then narrow it down until you find _where_ you crash. Then you can print out variables/arguments to see _why_ it crashes.

Comment: Improve your unhandled exception reporting so you *know* why it crashes.  Write an event handler for AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException and log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().

Answer (score 0):

You could look at destructors or copy constructors.

Building in release mode can optimize things like unnecessary object copies.

What happens when you start the program from command line and attach to it afterwards?

Comment: After program crashed I started debugger and now I know where it crashes, although I didn't figure out why (but I'm going to do so). Anyway, it is a little weird that it crashed if debug version started using command line, but doesn't crash if it is started from VS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While there are various kinds of undefined behaviors that can magically work fine in debug but not in release, or on one system but not another, or maybe only triggers noticeable behavior once in a full moon, probably the most common culprit for single-threaded code is *uninitialized memory*.

Most of the time this would be an *uninitialized variable*. It could also be a memory block that is allocated (like a buffer full of garbage) but wasn't filled, yet the code assumed it to be. Debug builds of some popular compilers have a tendency to zero out newly allocated memory, whether on the stack or heap, while release builds don't do this. They even have some debugging tools out there that deliberately fill memory with garbage to help catch these kinds of errors at runtime.

We're plagued by these in a legacy C system we work on. I'd say about 80% of the time, when we encounter such situations in single-threaded code, it's due to uninitialized memory of some sort (typically uninitialized variable). For multithreaded code which tends to exhibit timing-specific problems, that is a data race more often than not.

It's very important to practice safe practices to avoid undefined behaviors like this, since as you can see, it can become quite a pain reproducing the problem in the first place let alone narrowing down where the problem is in the code. Undefined behavior really is undefined which is what's so dangerous avoid it - it might work sometimes and sometimes not, on some systems and not others, and the fact that it works sometimes is what makes these bugs the nastiest (something that fails every time would actually be a whole lot better).

Another common beginner one that can be quite a head scratcher is failing to make a base class virtual while deleting through a base pointer. While not nearly as common, it can certainly lead to some very perplexing behavior on the systems I've tested. Again, it's hard to know in advance what your problem is with such a vague description, but it's typically going to be undefined behavior of some sort.

Comment: As I explained, the weird is that debug version crashes if it is issued from the command line, but doesn't crash if it is issued using Visual Studio, Debug mode. Anyway, thanks for the try.

Comment: @Vladmir That also happens with undefined behavior like the cases I described above (uninitialized memory, e.g.). You can also get cases where you can crash in debug builds without the debugger running but crash in debug builds with the debugger running, crash in release builds with the debugger running but not crash in release builds with the debugger running and not crash in debug builds with/without the debugger running... crash with one compiler/linker setting but not the other, etc. All of these symptoms can be expected with these kinds of issues.